# Polar Decomposition of a Complex Scalar Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems

People often write a complex scalar field via polar decomposition. What does this parametrization precisely mean?

To be more explicit consider the following Lagrangian of a complex scalar field with a $ U(1) $ symmetry,
\begin{equation} 
{\cal L} = - m ^2 \left| \phi \right| ^2 - \frac{ \lambda }{ 4} \left| \phi \right| ^4 + \left| \partial _\mu \phi \right| ^2 
\end{equation}

We can then make a field transformation,
\begin{equation} 
\phi (x) = \rho (x) e ^{ i \theta (x) } 
\end{equation} 
We typically refer to $ \rho (x) $ and $ \theta (x) $ as real scalar fields, but this is a strange for a couple reasons. Firstly, the $ \rho (x) $ field is positive definite. This is a boundary condition that we don't normally see in QFT. Its especially weird if $ \rho $ is quantized around $0$ since it can't ``go in the negative direction''.

The second reason I think calling $ \rho (x) $ and $ \theta (x) $ quantum fields is strange is because after we write out the Lagrangian we get,
\begin{equation} 
{\cal L} = - m ^2 \rho ^2 - \frac{ \lambda }{ 4} \rho ^4 + \partial _\mu \rho \partial ^\mu \rho + \rho ^2 \partial _\mu \theta \partial ^\mu \theta 
\end{equation} 
The $ \theta (x) $ field doesn't have a proper kinetic term and so can't be a propagating field!

If these objects aren't quantum fields then how should I think about them?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it, but isn't $\rho$ just the radius (hence it is positive definite) and $\theta$ the angle of the Higgs potential (the Mexican hat)?

Comment: @Hunter: Basically, yes. But in this reparameterization  are we justified in calling $\rho$ and $\theta$ fields and use them for example in scattering computations? I think the answer is no, but I have seen people refer to them as fields.

Comment: I think this is only true for a classical field theory. Otherwise, if you consider $\phi$ as a field composed of creation and annihilation operators, it is not clear that you can make such a decomposition.

Comment: @JSchwinger: I agree it isn't clear how that would work or whether it can be done at all...

Comment: I think this kind of separation is used to illustrate, for instance, Goldstone theorem (with a Mexican hat potential). With a decomposition $\rho = \rho_0 + \rho'$, you will find (with some redefinition) a kinetic term for $\theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion arises from indistinct usage of the term **scalar fields** when referring to a *physical field*, and when referring to *scalar functions*. I will try to answer your question clarifying separately these elements:

- Scalar field vs Scalar function
- Complex numbers' polar representation
- What this parametrization means...

**Scalar field vs Scalar function:**
In Mathematics a scalar function is any function mapping some *vector space* to its *body* (taking several arguments and returning a number, see *Vector Space* in Wikipedia). 
In Quantum Field Theory (QFT), the field function describing a boson's field is usually called a scalar field, because it has the mathematical properties of a scalar function, and also because of its transformation properties (see [V. Parameswaran Nair-Chapter2](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b106781) for a simple view, more serious definitions [R.Blumenhagen-Chapter2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-00450-6_2)). But most of all, while a scalar field is a scalar function, it describes a quantized field, meaning it will have further mathematical constraints. See also *Scalar Field* in Wikipedia.

**Complex number polar representation:**
This is one of the several ways we can represent complex numbers in terms of two separate real numbers (very well covered in *Complex Number* in Wikipedia). Any complex number can be expressed in this representation:
if $c=a+ib$ is a complex number with $a$ and $b$ the real and imaginary components, you can always find $\rho=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta=\arccos{\frac{a}{\rho}}=\arcsin{\frac{b}{\rho}}$, which is easy to infer from the geometrical representation of complex numbers in a 2D Euclidean space. From here you get the restriction of $\rho > 0$, but this does limit this representation, i.e. you can represent all complex numbers.

**What this parametrization means:**
$\phi$ here is both a scalar field in the QFT sense, and also a mathematical scalar field or function since it maps from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{C}$. The transformation $$\phi_{(x)}=\rho_{(x)} e^{i\theta_{(x)}}$$ is using the polar representation to express $\phi$ in terms of two mathematical scalar functions $\rho$ and $\theta$, each of them mapping from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

But one must bear in mind that $\rho$ and $\theta$ are not physical scalar fields, thus after substitution into the Lagrangian you have only varied the mathematical expression (thus the ``strange kinetic energy term for $\theta$''). In other terms, although both $\rho$ and $\theta$ make up the physical scalar function necessary to characterize your scalar field $\phi$, they are not separate scalar fields by themselves. So, your mathematical parametrization of $\phi$ does not translate into a physical decomposition of a boson field into 2 other boson fields.